# Dúvida em relação ao zoom no Media Query

Tags: html, css, zoom

Quero fazer um design responsivo, a versão de mobile já está pronta e funcionando perfeitamente, porém ao dar zoom o layout quebra. Como faço para corrigi-lo, ou melhor, usar zoom no media query? Existe alguma solução para isso? Grato desde já.

Comment: Tente colocar dentro da `<head>` da sua página `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` e testa.

Comment: Continua o mesmo amigo, eu já estou utilizando <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">, percebi que afeta mais nos itens que possui margins e no menu de navegação.

Comment: Deve afetar quase tudo onde vc usou valores em % e não valores fixos como PX, REM e EM. É possível acessar o página por um link?

Comment: Se não tiver um link para gente ver coloque aqui tudo que tem na página de HTML e CSS

Comment: Descobri o problema amigo, usei valores em % ao invés dos valores em PX. Testei e resolveu, muito obrigado!

Comment: Posso publicar então o comentário que fiz uma como Resposta para vc?

Comment: Claro, fique a vontade.

Comment: Jovem publiquei a resposta, se te ajudei de alguma forma por favor considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita" `✔`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro passo seria colocar o *meta* *viewport* no `<head>` da página para evitar qualquer problema de escala dos elementos e da página na tela do dispositivo. Na *viewport* também é aconselhável que se use o `width=device-width`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Mais detalhes sobre a : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Agora sobre o problema de Zoom em alguns elementos é porque provavelmente vc usou *valores em porcentagem neles %*

Tudo que tem o valor em % é afetado pelo Zoom. Para corrigir isso use valores fixos como PX, REM e EM onde for possível.