# Dimensionamento de Layout

Tags: css

Como resolver este problema de layout.Ao reduzir a tela a div contrai ,não ocupando todo espaço da tela.Basicamente defini uma largura e uma altura em px.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Thiago tudo bom, não ficou muito claro o que precisa, mas se definiu em px a dimensão de largura e altura essa medida é fixa indiferente do tamanho da sua tela.
Para um preenchimento total tu pode usar tanto a porcentagem em width 100% como também para altura usar a medida vh.

Comment: pode disponibilizar o código css que estás a utilizar?

Comment: Coloca seu código aí :P pra ver o que pode estar causando isso, mas se eu entendi direito, você está usando a `largura` em `px`, ao invés disso, a defina usando `%` - `width: 100%;` Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa avisa que edito!

Comment: Isto deveria ser colocado como um comentário, e não como uma resposta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Não tenho direito de comentar, até quando tentei, acusou que precisava de 50 pontos, e como ninguém havia respondido até o momento eu quis ajudá-lo

Comment: dê uma olhadinha melhor nesses fatores antes numa próxima vez!

Comment: Veja isso pode te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288053/media-query-para-diferentes-n%C3%ADveis-de-zoom/288067#288067 e isso tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271872/d%C3%BAvida-em-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-zoom-no-media-query/271885#271885

Comment: consegui resolver com o % .Valeu pela ajuda!!

Comment: O fato de não poder comentar não significa q pode usar esse campo de forma errada, para comentarios. Recomendo que evite fazer isso, pois corre o risco de ser negativado e o sistema te bloquear de responder no site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hipótese

Baseando-se na imagem disponibilizada, você possui um bloco com certo valor de altura e fundo cinza. E precisa que este bloco se estenda horizontalmente na página em todas as ocasiões.

## Código

Seguindo o que foi mencionado, este resultado pode ser atingido utilizando de tal código:

```css
html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
```

### Explicando

As duas primeiras linhas do CSS servem para garantir que seu bloco esteja colado nas bordas da página. Já a terceira linha com a classe `.header` é a classe que seria aplicada no seu bloco cinza da imagem, utilizei o valor de `50px` como estimulativo.

Mas o mais importante é o `width: 100%;`, primeira propriedade da classe `.header` pois ele faz com que o elemento sempre tenha a largura equivalente a `100%` da largura do primeiro elemento pai encontrado. Como suponho que não há nenhum elemento como pai dele, o elemento será o próprio documento html, sendo assim ficará `100%` relativo a página toda.